# Use an opengis xsd to validate an xml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xmllint, opengis

I am trying to use an xsd downloaded from opengis to validate an xml.

I downloaded the xsd files from http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/ (version `20060504`).

I wanted to load the xsd I need ([gmd.xsd](http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gmd/gmd.xsd)) in python using lxml. Since there are includes I had problems and found out I had to do `xinclude()` before. Now the code I'm using to load the xsd is

```
schema_xml = etree.parse("schema/19139/20060504/gmd/gmd.xsd")
schema_xml.xinclude()
schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_xml)
```

But it fails with this error

```
XMLSchemaParseError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[146], line 1
----> 1 schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_xml)

File src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi:89, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__()

XMLSchemaParseError: complex type 'EX_TemporalExtent_Type', attribute 'base':
The QName value '{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}AbstractObject_Type' does not
resolve to a(n) simple type definition., line 16
```

I then tried using xmllint from bash

```
xmllint --schema schema/19139/20060504/gmd/gmd.xsd file.xml --noout
```

Which also fails with a long series of errors. The first 10 lines are

```
warning: failed to load external entity "http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd"
schema/19139/20060504/gmd/metadataApplication.xsd:8: element import: Schemas parser warning : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd'. Skipping the import.
warning: failed to load external entity "http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd"
schema/19139/20060504/gmd/metadataEntity.xsd:8: element import: Schemas parser warning : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd'. Skipping the import.
warning: failed to load external entity "http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gss/gss.xsd"
schema/19139/20060504/gmd/spatialRepresentation.xsd:8: element import: Schemas parser warning : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gss/gss.xsd'. Skipping the import.
warning: failed to load external entity "http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd"
schema/19139/20060504/gmd/spatialRepresentation.xsd:9: element import: Schemas parser warning : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd'. Skipping the import.
warning: failed to load external entity "http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd"
schema/19139/20060504/gmd/citation.xsd:8: element import: Schemas parser warning : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/gco/gco.xsd'. Skipping the import.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [xmlschema](https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/) succesfully for validation of **xml** against an **xsd schema** ([Doc](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```
import xmlschema

schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema('xml_validate.xsd')
res = schema.is_valid('xml_validate.xml')
print(res)
```

Output should be `True` in case of valid xml.